# Does MINLOC work for arrays beginning at index 0? (Fortran 90/95)

Tags: c, arrays, fortran, min, intrinsics

After using C for a while, I went back to Fortran and allocated the arrays in my code from index 0 to N:

```
real(kind=dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: a 
allocate(a(0:50))
```

I needed to find the index of the minimum absolute value of the array, so I used MINLOC, and to check this I compared it to MINVAL:

```
minloc(abs(a(:)))
minval(abs(a))
```

The result of MINLOC was index `42` but the result of MINVAL corresponded to `41`. Here is the relevant section from the output:

```
Index i    a(i) 

39         0.04667    
40         0.02222    
41         0.00222           !This was clearly the minimum value
42         0.02667

MINLOC = 42
MINVAL = 0.00222
```

I assume this is something to do with the Fortran intrinsic not handling arrays with index 0 correctly, since it is not standard Fortran style to declare arrays in this way (but it is still permitted!).

Can anyone confirm this or offer a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your array `a` indeed starts at index 0, but you did not use that. You searched for a minimum of array `abs(a(:))`. This anonymous array expression starts at 1 as all arrays do by default.

But even if you used `a` the result would be the same and is consistent with how array argument passing works in Fortran.

The Fortran standard clearly states:

> The i subscript returned lies in the range 1 to ei , where ei is the
>   extent of the idimension of ARRAY. If ARRAY has size zero, all
>   elements of the result are zero.

Lower bounds are not automatically passed with the array if you used assumed shape arguments. For example if you have your own function

```
  function f(arg)
    real :: arg(:)
```

`arg` starts always at 1 no matter where the actual argument started in the calling code.

You can change it to start at some other value

```
  function f(arg)
    real :: arg(-42:)
```

and it would be indexed starting from that value.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I suppose my assumption was that a(:) referred to the full range of the array, no matter what that may be, but of course it does not. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

There are two simple methods to handle complication of adjusting the indices obtained from minloc(): One is simply adding lbound() - 1 for all indices, and the other is using an array pointer with 1-based indices. An example code may look like this:

```
program test
implicit none
integer, allocatable, target :: a(:,:)
integer, pointer :: anew(:,:)
integer :: loc(2)

allocate( a( 0:4, 2:5 ), source= 10 )  !! make an array filled with 10

a( 2, 3 ) = -700                       !! set the minimum value

loc(:) = minloc( a )                   !! minloc() receives "a" with 1-based indices
print *, loc(:)                        !! so we get [3,2]
print *, a( loc(1), loc(2) )           !! 10 (wrong result...)

!! Method (1) : adjust indices manually

loc(:) = loc(:) + lbound( a ) - 1
print *, a( loc(1), loc(2) )           !! -700 (now a correct result)

!! Method (2) : use array pointer with 1-based indices

anew( 1:, 1: ) => a

loc(:) = minloc( anew )
print *, loc(:)                        !! we get [3,2] again
print *, anew( loc(1), loc(2) )        !! -700  (this time, no need to adjust indices)

end program
```